# requireJS not updating, still references a deleted file

Tags: requirejs

I used to reference a file called `OptionRendererController.js`, but I deleted the reference and the file. When I grep my app's directory for OptionRenderer, no results appear, and I've made sure to include `urlArgs: "buset=" + (new Date()).getTime()` to prevent browser caching, and I restart the python server on which I'm running my app, but I still get a 404 error on the deleted `OptionRendererController.js` file. How can I make sure my app no longer references that file?

Answer (score 0):

It worked after I restarted Chrome.

Comment: I can recommend installing [Clear Cache addon](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clear-cache/cppjkneekbjaeellbfkmgnhonkkjfpdn) and making clicking the "recycle" icon before reloading a habit.